# How to properly install deployer?

Tags: php-deployer

I am trying to install and use [deployer](https://deployer.org/download/) so I run this command `curl -LO https://deployer.org/deployer.phar` to install it.
And try to move `deployer.phar` to `/usr/usr/local/bin/dep` as the [docs](https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started.html) instructs but it's not working:
Error: `mv: cannot stat 'deployer.phar': No such file or directory`
How do I correctly install it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i did it following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/automatically-deploy-laravel-applications-deployer-ubuntu), the problem was that it wasn't installing because it needs sudo privileges, so i followed these steps:

```
1: curl -LO https://deployer.org/deployer.phar
2: sudo mv deployer.phar /usr/local/bin/dep
3: sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dep
```

As the [docs](https://deployer.org/download/) instructs, but with sudo.